# Connect to gcd datastore using Dart gcloud API

Tags: dart, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to connect my local gcd-tool to my **inner-docker** Dart app using [gcloud package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/gcloud).

According to [gcd doc](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/), I simply need to set 2 environment variables to redirect python/java libraries:

```
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8080
export DATASTORE_DATASET=<your-local-dataset-id>
```

But dart gcloud package seems to ignore that: **every entity saved is going online**. I can't figure out how to set the datastore host.

So, is there any way to use this package on a datastore emulated locally with gcd-tool and outside of a "gcloud preview" context? Should I use another package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not supported
https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis/issues/4